# Problem when creating C# derived components on Visual C# 2010 Express

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I used to create components by writing a derived class from some other component (like WebBrowser, for example), and then after successfully running my application the component would appear in the Toolbox as a normal component that I can drag and drop in my forms.

After installing Windows 7 and reloading my old solution, even though I rebuild it and run it successfully several times, I get and error every time I try to open the designer for any form that contains any of these derived components, telling me that couldn't load  the component.

Also, since after running my app, my derived components always appear in the toolbox, if I try to drag and drop it to any form (any form that doesn't already contain any of these components since if it does I couldn't open the designer) I get an error box telling me that the component couldn't be loaded and that will be removed (again) from the toolbox. Any suggestions?

Comment: Designer Stacktrace would be helpfull

Comment: Instances of this error (1)  
 
1.   There is no stack trace or error line information available for this error.  
 
   
Help with this error  
 
Could not find an associated help topic for this error. Check Windows Forms Design-Time error list   
 
   
Forum posts about this error  
 
Search the MSDN Forums for posts related to this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, changed to x86 and that fixed it. It was on x64. Not sure why this caused a problem though.